# Play audio from array of bytes in android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to stream live audio from one device to many devices . I am recording my voice in android and while its recording i am sending bytes to server and again receiving those bytes on different devices what i am getting is array of bytes and i am getting so many array of bytes every second . Now want to play those bytes as audio . media player require file to play but i cant save it into file because data is still coming i am very confused either i am doing it in wrong way . Actua i want to made two apps in one app we speak something and in another app we can listen what is someone speaking at that side in real time .

Comment: Have you achieved it. Im also trying the same now

Answer (score 1):

The [AudioTrack](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack) class allows streaming of PCM audio buffers, via `write (byte[] audioData, int offsetInBytes, int sizeInBytes)` (among other methods).